# Multiple bijective linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $$T:V\rightarrow V$$ is a bijective linear transformation then can  $T^2$  also be a bijective linear transformation? Can $T^n$ also be bijective linear transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start an easy example:
$$I_n = I_n^2 = I_n^k$$

But the most easy way to think about this question is, if you look at the determinant and the determinant of matrix products.

$$det(A*B)=det(A)*det(B)$$

So if you have a bijective (non-singular,$\ det(T)\neq 0$) Transformation T follows:

$$det(T^n)=det(T)*det(T^{n-1})=det(T)*...*det(T)\neq 0$$

Thus $T^n$ is non-singular.

Else you would get
$$det(T^n)=det(T)*...*det(T)=0\quad => \quad det(T)=0$$
Thus T wouldn't be invertible (non-singular, bijective)

---

If $T$ is non-singular $T^n$ is non-singular.

Comment: Also if you multiply any invertible matrices (with the same dimensions), the product will always be invertible itself.
If$\ A,B \in GL_n(K)$, this is the set of invertible matrices with dimension n x n, $A*B \in GL_n(K)$

Comment: Can't it be proved by induction like T is bijective L.T.(linear transformation) then if we prove T^2  1-1 , onto and L.T. and then proving  T^n to be the same by induction

Comment: You don't have to use induction. $GL_n(K)$ is a Ring with 1. This is way stronger than any induction you can do.

Comment: If you can use a direct prove, always use it.
Induction is a dangerous game. If you don't watch the exact properties of the set you start in, you can fall into a deep hole.

I usually go with Counterargument > Direct Prove > Indirect Prove > Induction.

Comment: Sure .. thank you for helping Patrick Abraham

Comment: Could write a proof using Induction if you really want it, but I prefer it my way ^^

Comment: I can go both ways so nice of you  thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $T^n$ *must* be a bijective linear transformation.

A function has an inverse iff it's bijective. Since $T$ is bijective, it has an inverse, $T^{-1}$. So consider $(T^{-1})^n$ as a candidate for the inverse of $T^n$.
$$ (T^{-1})^n \circ T^n = (T^{-1})^{n-1} \circ T^{-1} \circ T \circ T^{n-1} = (T^{-1})^{n-1} \circ T^{n-1} = \cdots = T^{-1} \circ T = id$$

Similarly, $T^n \circ (T^{-1})^n$ is also the identity map. Since $T^n$ has an inverse, it's bijective.

Also, as a composition of linear functions, it's linear, but that probably was the easier thing to show.

Comment: Can't it be proved by induction like T is bijective L.T.(linear transformation) then if we prove T^2  1-1 , onto and L.T. and then proving  T^n to be the same by induction

Comment: Yeah, this proof also should use induction on $n$, if it were formalized. Also, you mention "1-1 and onto". That's one way to prove bijectivity, but so is finding an inverse, and I feel that's more natural for this problem. The other way still works though.

Comment: Ok thank you Henry Swanson

Answer (score 1):

In fact, any composite of bijective linear transformations on $V$ is also bijective linear.

For the case that given two bijective linear $T_1,T_2:V\rightarrow V$, 
there exist two linear $U_1,U_2:V\rightarrow V$ such that
$$U_1T_1=T_1U_1=U_2T_2=T_2U_2={\rm id}_V.$$
By the associative property of linear transformations, we have
\begin{align}
(T_1T_2)(U_2U_1)&=T_1(T_2U_2)U_1=T_1{\rm id}_VU_1=T_1U_1={\rm id}_V,\\
(U_2U_1)(T_1T_2)&=U_2(U_1T_1)T_2=U_2{\rm id}_VT_2=U_2T_2={\rm id}_V.
\end{align}
Thus $T_1T_2$ is bijective with the inverse $U_2U_1$, and we may get the same result for
$n$ linear bijective $T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_n:V\rightarrow V$ inductively.

Comment: Can't it be proved by induction like T is bijective L.T.(linear transformation) then if we prove T^2  1-1 , onto and L.T. and then proving  T^n to be the same by induction

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be a linear bijective transformation with $T:V \rightarrow V$.

Thus $\exists\ \hat{T} : T \circ \hat{T} = id$

Base: $T^n$ is bijective may n be, without loss of generality, equal to 2. $n=2$

$ id = T \circ id \circ \hat{T} = T \circ T \circ \hat{T} \circ \hat{T} = T^2 \circ \hat{T^2}$

Let n be arbitrary but fixed, with $id=T^n\circ\hat{T^n}$

$n\rightarrow n+1$

$T^{n+1}\circ\hat{T^{n+1}}=T\circ T^n\circ \hat{T^{n}}\circ\hat{T} \stackrel{\text{base}}{=} T \circ id \circ \hat{T} = T \circ \hat{T} = id$

Thus $T^n$ is bijective. $\square$

Comment: Thank you so very much Patrick Abraham for helping ... 